# TypeError: b is not an object - jchartfx

Tags: jquery, jchartfx

Upon running:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

function PopulateProductSales(chart1) { 
        var items = '<?php echo $json ?>';
        chart1.setDataSource(items);
 }
});  
</script>
```

the console returns:

```
TypeError: b is not an object

...null;if("string"==typeof b)return c==e?b:null;for(var d=Object.getPrototypeOf(b)... jchartfx.system.js
```

in the console. If however, I run:

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 

function PopulateProductSales(chart1) {

       var items = [{
            "Month": "Jan 2014",
            "Posts": 12,
        }, {
            "Month": "Feb 2013",
            "Posts": 10,
        }, {
            "Month": "Mar 2013",
            "Posts": 16,
        }, {
            "Month": "Apr 2013",
            "Posts": 7,
        }, {
            "Month": "May 2012",
            "Posts": 1,
        }];

        chart1.setDataSource(items);
}

});
</script>
```

my chart/graph loads fine. Furthermore, the dynamic data is valid json, since observing the results in both console and http://jsonlint.com/ .

```
<script>
 var items = '<?php echo $json ?>';
 console.log(items);
</script>
```

ouputs:

```
[{"month":"May 2013","posts":2},{"month":"March 2013","posts":1}...]
```

to the console. The dynamic data is *exactly* the same as the static! All jchartfx libraries are loaded correctly, the DOM get's parsed OK - so why won't the software work with my dynamic data?

Answer (score 1):

Either your JSON is broken, or the API is waiting for an actual `Object` as in `{}`.

Try using http://jsonlint.com

Comment: @ Pierre As far as I'm aware, the json is fine - it's been checked through JSONLint. Do you have knowledge of the jChartfx API?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<script>
 var items = '<?php echo $json ?>';
</script>
```

use:

```
<script>
 var items = <?php echo $json ?>;
</script>
```

So, the 'delimiters' were giving me the problem.